# JQuery validate doesn't work with IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-validate, validation

I'm working on this website:

http://aimmgm.goexpo.mx/index.php/registro/generales

That's basically a form and what I'm trying to do is to validate it using a jquery plug in. It works just fine in Chrome and Firefox. But IE seems to have troubles with it since it doesn't validate the fields.

So, any hint of what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry guys. I was using and old version of JQuery Validate. I updated it to the latest version and it works perfectly. Sorry for the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: would suggest that you answer your question with the content of your above comment and mark it as the answer, this greatly helps others searching with similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys. I was using and old version of JQuery Validate. I updated it to the latest version and it works perfectly. Sorry for the question. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#formId').submit(function(){
    if(!$(this).valid()){
       return false;
    }
});
```